# Issues concatenating to an array constant for options_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
<%= select_tag :role, options_for_select(Project::COMPANY_ROLES.concat(['Other...']), @relationship.role) %>
```

For some reason it concatenates "Other..." to COMPANY_ROLES but saves this past the view that was loaded.

1st Run = 1 option of "Other..."

2nd Run = 2 options of "Other..."

3rd Run = 3 options of "Other..."

I simply want it to concatenate during run-time and not save state.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= select_tag :role, options_for_select(Project::COMPANY_ROLES + ['Other...'], @relationship.role) %>
```